# Strange behavior with SELECT WHERE A="$var" SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I looked for an answer but could not find it as the issue seems to be slightly different here.

```
$vid = $_SESSION['ID_Vendor'];
echo "ID: $vid";
$q = 'SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
  FROM restaurant res
   INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
  ON vd.ID_Vendor=res.ID_Vendor AND res.ID_Vendor="$vid" ORDER BY business_name ASC';
```

The variable $vid has indeed a value (equal to 2 in this case, but it could be different), HOWEVER, when I specifically set

```
 WHERE res.ID_Vendor=2
```

my query returns the correct and expected list of values, but when, instead, I use

```
 WHERE res.ID_Vendor="$vid"
```

with "$vid", the echo of my values is simply empty.

Below is the full snippet of the code to also echo the output.
Thanks for your help.

```
 $vid = $_SESSION['ID_Vendor'];
 echo "ID: $vid";
 $q = 'SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
  FROM restaurant res
   INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
  ON vd.ID_Vendor=sfe.ID_Vendor AND res.ID_Vendor="$vid" ORDER BY   business_name ASC';
 $r = mysqli_query($connection, $q);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

  echo '>' . htmlspecialchars($row[0]) . '  ' . htmlspecialchars($row[1]) . '   ' . htmlspecialchars($row[2]) .'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Does this make any difference?

`$q = "SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
  FROM restaurant res
   INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
  ON vd.ID_Vendor=res.ID_Vendor AND res.ID_Vendor=$vid ORDER BY business_name ASC";`

Comment: Echo your query before you execute it and I think the problem will make itself obvious. You could avoid the problem entirely if you read up on prepared statements.

Comment: Darwin, thanks. But, why would a prepared statement make a difference? I would think that a stored procedure would work instead, isn't that right? Let me try both.

Comment: Among other things, prepared statements handle the quoting and type-matching of query parameters automatically for you.

Comment: A simple **`echo $q;`** would have revealed one of the problems. The observed behavior is not "strange". It's well defined and well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I raised the idea, I suppose I should illustrate the use of prepared statements.

Using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) one would proceed as follows (assuming `$connection` has been successfully initialized):

```
// The indentation here is purely a matter of personal preference
$query = 'SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
            FROM restaurant res
            INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
              ON vd.ID_Vendor = res.ID_Vendor
            WHERE res.ID_Vendor = ?
            ORDER BY business_name ASC';

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $vid);  // 's' assumes $vid is string; use 'i' for int
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo '>' . htmlspecialchars($row[0]) . '  ' . htmlspecialchars($row[1]) . '   ' . htmlspecialchars($row[2]) .'</option>';
}
```

The idiom is the same using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The format of the [PDO data source name (DSN)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) is documented online.

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // define these vars elsewhere
$query = 'SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
            FROM restaurant res
            INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
              ON vd.ID_Vendor = res.ID_Vendor
            WHERE res.ID_Vendor = :vid
            ORDER BY business_name ASC';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':vid' => $vid));
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    echo '>' . htmlspecialchars($row[0]) . '  ' . htmlspecialchars($row[1]) . '   ' . htmlspecialchars($row[2]) .'</option>';
}
```

In both cases I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not recognize variable in apostrophes pair ''. Put your variable in "". EG:

```
"WHERE res.ID_Vendor='$vid'"
```

Comment: Thank you @ThangTD and Luweiq, your solution solved the problemI still want to try prepared statements as proposed by Darwin as they even improve security.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code:

---

Firstly, this won't work and will echo `$vid` literally.

```
echo "ID: $vid";
```

This will return: `ID: $vid`

You'll need to concat the string with the variable, it should be:

```
echo "ID: " . $vid;
```

This will return: `ID: 2`

---

Secondly, your query won't work:

```
$q = 'SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
  FROM restaurant res
   INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
  ON vd.ID_Vendor=res.ID_Vendor AND res.ID_Vendor="$vid" ORDER BY business_name ASC';
```

You should enclose the query with double quotes and your variable with single quotes instead:

```
$q = "SELECT business_name, vd.ID_Vendor, res.ID_RestaurantEstablishment 
  FROM restaurant res
   INNER JOIN vendor_data vd
  ON vd.ID_Vendor=res.ID_Vendor AND res.ID_Vendor='$vid' ORDER BY business_name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL, not like javascript or php, only single quote is allowed for string or char.

For MySQL, if the column type of res.id_vendor is number, res.id_vendor='1' is the same as res.id_vendor=1, so it is better always wrap the variable with single quote, as in **res.id_vendor='$vid'**

Lastly, comments on coding conventions: it is recommended to not mix upper case and lower case characters in column naming, use "_" as word delimiters, like

```
vd.id_vendor
res.id_restaurant_establishment
```